# update and return another string in a SQL function

Tags: sql-server-2005

I want to update a string and return a string in a SQL function.
The update works perfectly but the returning the string is not working,when i deactivate the sp_executesql the function returns the value. why we can't execute a command and return a different value.
please help me
the SQL FUNCTION

```
===========================================================
    set ANSI_NULLS ON
    set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    set nocount on
    go
===========================================================
    ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[autoid](@tablename varchar(max))
    RETURNS varchar(max)
    AS
     -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    BEGIN          


    declare @str1 varchar(max)
    declare @str2 varchar(max)
    declare @str3 varchar(max)
    declare @str4 varchar(max)
    declare @str5 varchar(max)
    declare @str6 varchar(max)
    declare @str7 nvarchar(max)
    declare @str8 int
    declare @str9 int
    declare @str10 int
    declare @str11 int
    declare @str12 int
    select @str8 = IDNO from control where tablename =  @tablename 
    select @str1 = shortname from control where tablename = @tablename 
    set @str3=  @str1
    set @str9=LEN(@str8)
    set @str11=26
    select @str10= @str11 - @str9
    select @str12=@str8 + 1
    while(@str10>0)
    BEGIN
    set @str1=@str1 + '0'
    select @str10 = @str10 - 1
    END
    select @str5 = @str1 + CAST ( @str12 AS VARCHAR(10) ) 
    set @str7='update control set IDNO = ' + CAST ( @str12 AS VARCHAR(100)) + ' where tablename = ''' + @tablename +''''
    execute sp_executesql @str7
    return @str5
    END
    ====================================================================================
```

Comment: Any reason why you give your variables so unintuitive names?

Comment: Could you elaborate on 'is not working'? What is the result? What do you expect? What is the input?

Comment: am trying to generate an auto id and return it to another stored procedure where insert function takes place. by giving some specific variables

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use a stored procedure for this. Functions can't have side effects including Updating tables.

You also can't execute stored procedures (including `sp_executesql`) from within a function (or at least not without resorting to a hack with `openrowset`)

You can return scalar values from a stored procedure by using `output` parameters.

Comment: Do you not get the error `Only functions and extended stored procedures can be executed from within a function.`?

Comment: @Niranjan - When you execute it with `select [dbo].[autoid]('SomeValue')` you should get that error.

Comment: no it did't.I checked and it ran perfectly.
but the problem was this function is not returning value